# WCF in Windows Forms Application

Tags: winforms, wcf

I'm tryin to run a WCF service within a Windows Forms Application. I copied and modified code found in the WCF samples from Microsoft. When running the WCF Sample the service shows up in a port monitor (CurrPorts) I use. When I run my code I can't see my service...

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace NoName.Server
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace="http://NoName")]
    public interface IApplicationService
    {
        [OperationContract()]
        NoName.Entities.MediaParameter[] GetParametersForMediaObject(string mediaObjectId);
        [OperationContract()]
        NoName.Entities.MediaParameter GetMediaParameter(string parameterId);
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace NoName.Server
{
    public class ApplicationService : IApplicationService
    {
        public Entities.MediaParameter[] GetParametersForMediaObject(string mediaObjectId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Entities.MediaParameter GetMediaParameter(string parameterId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running it from a Form as

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ApplicationService)))
   {
      host.Open();
   }
}
```

And the configuration in app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="NoName.Server.ApplicationService" behaviorConfiguration="ApplicationServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/NoName/ApplicationService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/NoName/ApplicationService  -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="NoName.Server.IApplicationService"/>
        <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at soap.tcp://localhost:8000/NoName/ApplicationService/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <!--For debugging purposes set the includeExceptionDetailInFaults attribute to true-->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ApplicationServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

It compiles without errors, no exceptions when I run it. It just won't exist. Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "It just won't exist"? You see it occupy a port in port monitor, so it exists ok.

Answer (score 2):

Well - you're using a `using` block, which is normally a good thing - but here, the service host will be closed again right away at the end of the `using` block - which is certainly **not** what you want!

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ApplicationService)))
{
    host.Open();   // host is opened here
}                  // host is disposed and closed here
```

So your `ServiceHost` was open and ready to receive requests - for a fraction of a second only... and then it was closed and disposed of since the `using { .. }` block ended.....

What you need to do is this:

- add a private member variable to e.g. your main form

  ```
    private ServiceHost _serviceHost = null;
  ```
- open that service host at some point in your code, e.g. in your method you have there:

  ```
  private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ApplicationService));
  }
  ```
- leave it open until e.g. the Winforms app closes (or the user choses some other menu item to actually close the service host)

Comment: Yes of course (with small amount of embaressment... ) :)
And now everything works just fine!

Comment: @user1062729: sometimes, deep into programming, you just don't see the forest for the trees anymore. Bet something like this has happened to anyone out there.